# What is the purpose of the line in between Sub ()s?

Tags: vba, excel, comments

In the VBA IDE there is a line in between Sub()s.  What is its meaning and why does it move position based on Comment structure?

[image: Pic - One lined comment]

[image: Pic - Two lined comment]

Answer (score 2):

The horizontal line has no real meaning - it's there solely to make it easier to see where one sub ends and the next one starts.

A comment line above the sub is deemed to be part of the sub.  A continued line above the sub is deemed to be part of the previous sub.

Comment: You mean "of the previous line"?

Comment: @A.S.H - not really - I was trying to get across that the fact that, if it was continued, it immediately makes it part of the previous sub, because otherwise the fact that it is a continuation of a **comment** would mean it should be part of this sub.  But being a continuation makes it part of the previous sub.  (Silly idea having continued comment lines - I can see why the IDE doesn't understand it.)

Comment: Didn't get what you meant by continuous line. Gotcha now.

Comment: 2 things should be noted here. First, neither comment is "part of the Sub" as far as the VBA grammar is concerned.  According  to the language specification, only lines between the `Sub` declaration and `End Sub` are part of the procedure.  Second, the placement of the line is a *VBE rendering* decision based on how [ProcOfLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264833.aspx) is implemented. Interestingly if you read the remarks in the linked documentation, the OP's screenshots appear to demonstrate a bug in the VBE object model.

Comment: @Comintern It gets even more interesting when a comment before a comment before a comment **is** part of the sub, but a comment before a blank line before a comment **is not**, but a blank line before a comment before a blank line before a comment **is**.  (And a continuation of a comment line always breaks everything.)

Comment: IKR?  Don't even get me started about [CountOfDeclarationLines](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/2656#issuecomment-278208920)...  FWIW, I've never understood putting a line continuation in a comment anyway - it's much easier to just, you know, comment the next line too.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the horizontal line separates the subs and the functions from each other. It is visible only in full module view:

[image]

If you want to avoid it, you can go to procedure view, where each procedure is visible alone on the VBE.

[image]

Comment: And, in that view, the continued comment is placed at the bottom of the previous sub, and the non-continued comment is placed at the top of the following sub.

Comment: Thank you.  That is helpful. I was also wondering why the "horizontal line" starts above the comment (helping me to see the comment is part of the next Sub() ) however, if I break my comment up into two lines or add a second comment below the first the "horizontal line" changes position.  Making the comment(s) look like it is apart of the previous Sub().  I am probably being a little anal.

Comment: OK, it works when you write your comments in the Procedure View.  Meaning the comment behaves and stay associated to the intended Sub().  Thank you again!